# Is list[i:j] guaranteed to be an empty list if list[j] precedes list[i]?

Tags: python, list, slice

[The Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) explains slice behavior when indices are negative, but I can't find documentation describing the behavior when the end index precedes the start index. (I've also looked at [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation), and perhaps I'm not reading carefully enough, but the answers there don't seem to address this point.)

The behavior that I observe is that an empty list is returned, which seems reasonable to me.  However, it also would seem reasonable to me for this to return a list of items between `i` and `j` in reversed order or to simply raise an exception.

Is `list[i:j]` guaranteed to be an empty list if `list[j]` precedes `list[i]`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, if `j <= i` is true, the resulting slice is empty, for *standard Python types*. To get the results in reverse order, you need to add a negative stride:

```
list[i:j:-1]
```

because *explicit is better than implicit*.

This is documented in [*Common Sequence Operations*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations), footnote 4:

> The slice of *s* from *i* to *j* is defined as the sequence of items with index *k* such that `i <= k < j`. If *i* or *j* is greater than `len(s)`, use `len(s)`. If *i* is omitted or `None`, use `0`. If `j` is omitted or `None`, use `len(s)`. **If *i* is greater than or equal to *j*, the slice is empty.**

Bold emphasis mine.

Custom types are free to interpret this differently.

Comment: Ah, *that's* where it's mentioned in the Python documentation.  Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: What do you mean with the italic "for standard Python types"?

Comment: @bamboon: handling of slices is type specific. The `list`, `tuple`, `str`, `bytes` and `range` types all behave like this, but if you implement your own type your `__getitem__` method is free to handle slices differently.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah ok, I thought this question was explicitly about `list`.

Comment: @bamboon: and I am pre-emptively heading off comments along the line of *does this apply to strings and tuples too?* and *but project X doesn't behave like that, is that a bug?*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah yeah, no offense. I was just confused and that's why I asked.

Comment: BTW, footnote 4 needs the context of footnote 3. The "If *i* is greater than or equal to *j*, the slice is empty." bit isn't true if *j* is negative (and that's why I posed my question with the slightly obtuse "if list[j] precedes list[i]" phrasing rather than "if j < i".

Comment: @jamesdlin: handling of negative indices is done before the rules of footnote 4 are applied, so `i` and `j` are positive by that point.

Comment: Right, that's the context of footnote 3 that I was referring to.